# Prevent pop-over windows from loading as _blank

Tags: html, loading, popover

My previous question as been **wrongly marked as duplicated** and it seems it got lost without any answer. So I'm rewording it :

I'm using < a > links to open HTML files in pop-over windows (using Clearbox script). **The problem is, if I click on it before the page is fully loaded, it opens itself in a _blank target**. I don't want it to happen so I'm looking for a way to prevent those files from being loaded out of a Clearbox window.

I optimized the Clearbox script loading the best I could, which works better but still not perfectly. That's why I've been thinking about loading those < a > elements at the very end of my page's loading process. **I'm not looking for a CSS fade-in effect as previously suggested**, I just don't want the element to exist at all (or at least to be inactive) until everything else is loaded.

Do you have any idea to help me with this ?

Comment: Can you move the Clearbox script to the `<head>` of the document? Or at least higher up, so that it gets loaded quicker?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help **must** include a minimal, complete and verifyable example. See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to create one. Please provide a jsfiddle or some form of code sample. As is now, your question can't be answered as we have next to no information. God knows what clearbox is..

Comment: do you want the <a> links appear after page fully loaded?

Comment: Garconis : it loads pretty fast already, but it still takes a few seconds on low connexions to be fully operationnal.

Comment: Rando Hinn. I'm not seeking debugging. The question seems pretty understandable. Thanks for your concern anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can hide  links in css like:

```
a{
    display:none;
}
```

and set their display to block when document is fully loaded:

```
$(window).load(function(){  
    $("a").css("display", "block");
});
```